# How to solve the issue "matlab can't reload cnngpu.dll" in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to run a CNN program with `trainNetwork`. CUDA is enabled. When I run, it causes an error:

```
matlab can't reload cnngpu.dll
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Yes, I have both parallel toolbox, deep learning toolbox

Comment: For the reference link, yes, I read, but it did not solve my issue. Otherwise, I used MATLAB2018b.